# Javascript Angular and UiBootstrap - templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have followed a book tutorial (Getting Mean by Simon Holmes) and have the following, which works:

```
var ratingStars = function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      thisRating : '=rating'
    },
    templateUrl: '/template/rating-stars.html'
  };
};
```

This loads the html from the file and applies it to the page correctly.

However, if I try adding UI Bootstrap ([LINK](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)) to the project, the above stops working. Can anyone tell me why?

The usage of the above function is outlined below:

```
table.table.table-striped.table-hover
    thead
      tr
        th Name
        th Rating
    tbody(ng-controller="empListCtrl")
      tr(ng-repeat="emp in data.empTest | filter:searchText"  ng-click="empRowClicked(emp)" )
        td{{emp.name}}
        td(rating-stars, rating="emp.rating")
```

Comment: you probably need to give more context for how this `ratingStars()` function is working. It's not clear how this is actually loading the resource to your page

Comment: Hi @thanksd, I've updated to show how it is used.

Comment: Just to make sure... did you check console to see if there are any exceptions?

Comment: Hi @kriskot, Yes, I did, and there was nothing.

Comment: UI Bootstrap also has a "rating" directive. It's possible that your `rating` attribute is conflicting w/the UI Bootstrap rating directive. Try giving that attribute a different name. Note that the UI Bootstrap directive is called `uib-rating` but that might be new (they didn't used to prefix their directives w/"uib" in the old days).

Comment: Hi @SunilD., I've tried changing the attribute to starRating but still no luck, I'm afraid.